# How to Manually Upload Files via FTP

Tags: wp-redirect, ftp

I am helping a friend who has a site self-hosted via Wordpress. They have access to their FTP. Now I am familiar with manually updating files through the FTP and that is how I usually update my sites. (Because I deal with mostly static sites).

The question, how can I upload the new coded site to be the www.example.com to show instead of the current website? Can I redirect the index.php of the current site to go to the new code?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just delete the Wordpress install folder or move it to another directory, then you have the folder to yourself, upload your coded site and you should be good. You could rename the wp-config.php file to wp-configX.php and also delete the .htaccess file if it is there and then have your site work in that folder as well.

Check if the Wordpress install is in a different folder besides the root html folder. If so, and www.example.com is still sending you the the WP install, then check for an .htaccess in the root web folder as well. usually this is something like ( html | httpdocs | www | public_html )